# Способ получить координаты всех элементов массива без FOR

Tags: python, numpy

Есть массив **arr** с данными (по сути дела они не важны).

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Необходимо получить список координат центра каждого элемента массива. Предполагается что длина каждой ячейка равна 1. То есть нужно получить следующее:

```
(0.5, 0.5)
(0.5, 1.5)
(0.5, 2.5)
(1.5, 0.5)
(1.5, 1.5)
(1.5, 2.5)
(2.5, 0.5)
(2.5, 1.5)
(2.5, 2.5)
```

Делаю так:

```
for row in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for col in range(arr.shape[1]):
        print (row + 0.5, col + 0.5)
```

Собственно вопрос. Как избавиться от вложенных **for** друг в друга? Чую - наверняка есть какой-нибудь простой метод из [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без for можно сделать вот так:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(3 * 3).reshape(3, 3)

grid = np.mgrid[:arr.shape[0], :arr.shape[1]] + 0.5

print(grid.reshape(2, -1).T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужны пары (`tuples`) координат, то лучше воспользуйтесь [решением от @Avernial](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621506/211923).
Если вам нужно два отдельных массива координат `X` и `Y`, то можно воспользоваться функцией [np.unravel_index()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
In [291]: x, y = np.unravel_index(np.arange(arr.size), arr.shape)

In [292]: x
Out[292]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)

In [293]: y
Out[293]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)

In [296]: x + 0.5
Out[296]: array([ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5,  2.5,  2.5,  2.5])

In [297]: y + 0.5
Out[297]: array([ 0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  0.5,  1.5,  2.5])
```

Можно также создать массив координат:

```
In [305]: np.vstack(np.unravel_index(np.arange(arr.size), arr.shape)).T
Out[305]:
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]], dtype=int64)

In [306]: np.vstack(np.unravel_index(np.arange(arr.size), arr.shape)).T + 0.5
Out[306]:
array([[ 0.5,  0.5],
       [ 0.5,  1.5],
       [ 0.5,  2.5],
       [ 1.5,  0.5],
       [ 1.5,  1.5],
       [ 1.5,  2.5],
       [ 2.5,  0.5],
       [ 2.5,  1.5],
       [ 2.5,  2.5]])
```